# Python concatenate (multiple) strings to number

Tags: python, numpy

I have a python list `['a1', 'b1', 'a2', 'b2','a3', 'b3']`. Set `m=3` and I want get this list using loops, because here `m=3` could be a larger number such as `m=100`.

Since we can have

```py
m = 3

['a' + str(i) for i in np.arange(1,m+1)]
# ['a1', 'a2', 'a3']

['b' + str(i) for i in np.arange(1,m+1)]
# ['b1', 'b2', 'b3']
```

then I try to get `['a1', 'b1', 'a2', 'b2','a3', 'b3']` using

```py
[ ['a','b'] + str(i) for i in np.arange(1,m+1)]
```

and have `TypeError: can only concatenate list (not "str") to list`

Then I  try

```py
[ np.array(['a','b']) + str(i) for i in np.arange(1,m+1)]
```

and I still get errors as `UFuncTypeError: ufunc 'add' did not contain a loop with signature matching types (dtype('<U1'), dtype('<U1')) -> None`.

How can I fix the problem? And even more, how to get something like `['a1', 'b1', 'c1', 'a2', 'b2','c2','a3', 'b3', 'c3']` through similar ways?

Comment: Use `range` instead of `np.arange` for these iterations.  '+' only works for like objects - lists with lists, strings with strings.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A simple combined `list` comprehension would work as pointed out in the [@j1-lee's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72653970/5218354) (and later in other answers).

```py
import string


def letter_number_loop(n, m):
    letters = string.ascii_letters[:n]
    numbers = range(1, m + 1)
    return [f"{letter}{number}" for number in numbers for letter in letters]
```

Similarly, one could use [`itertools.product()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.product), as evidenced in [Nick's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72653982/5218354), to obtain substantially the same:

```
import itertools


def letter_number_it(n, m):
    letters = string.ascii_letters[:n]
    numbers = range(1, m + 1)
    return [
        f"{letter}{number}"
        for number, letter in itertools.product(numbers, letters)]
```

However, it is possible to write a NumPy-vectorized approach, making use of the fact that if the `dtype` is `object`, the operations do follow the Python semantics.

```py
import numpy as np


def letter_number_np(n, m):
    letters = np.array(list(string.ascii_letters[:n]), dtype=object)
    numbers = np.array([f"{i}" for i in range(1, m + 1)], dtype=object)
    return (letters[None, :] + numbers[:, None]).ravel().tolist()
```

Note that the final [`numpy.ndarray.tolist()`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.ndarray.tolist.html) could be avoided if whatever will consume the output is capable of dealing with the NumPy array itself, thus saving some relatively small but definitely appreciable time.

---

## Inspecting Output

The following do indicate that the functions are equivalent:

```
funcs = letter_number_loop, letter_number_it, letter_number_np

n, m = 2, 3
for func in funcs:
    print(f"{func.__name__!s:>32}  {func(n, m)}")
```

```
              letter_number_loop  ['a1', 'b1', 'a2', 'b2', 'a3', 'b3']
                letter_number_it  ['a1', 'b1', 'a2', 'b2', 'a3', 'b3']
                letter_number_np  ['a1', 'b1', 'a2', 'b2', 'a3', 'b3']
```

---

## Benchmarks

For larger inputs, this is substantially faster, as evidenced by these benchmarks:

```py
timings = {}
k = 16
for n in (2, 20):
    for k in range(1, 10):
        m = 2 ** k
        print(f"n = {n}, m = {m}")
        timings[n, m] = []
        base = funcs[0](n, m)
        for func in funcs:
            res = func(n, m)
            is_good = base == res
            timed = %timeit -r 64 -n 64 -q -o func(n, m)
            timing = timed.best * 1e6
            timings[n, m].append(timing if is_good else None)
            print(f"{func.__name__:>24}  {is_good}  {timing:10.3f} µs")
```

to be plotted with:

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pandas as pd

n_s = (2, 20)
fig, axs = plt.subplots(1, len(n_s), figsize=(12, 4))
for i, n in enumerate(n_s):
    partial_timings = {k[1]: v for k, v in timings.items() if k[0] == n}
    df = pd.DataFrame(data=partial_timings, index=[func.__name__ for func in funcs]).transpose()
    df.plot(marker='o', xlabel='Input size / #', ylabel='Best timing / µs', ax=axs[i], title=f"n = {n}")
```

[image: benchmarks]

These show that the explicitly looped versions (`letter_number_loop()` and `letter_number_it()`) are somewhat comparable, while the NumPy-vectorized (`letter_number_np()`) fares much better relatively quickly for larger inputs, up to ~2x speed-up.

Comment: I do love a good chart! Great answer.

Comment: letter_number_np is significantly faster than other suggestions when the data are "large" e.g., m=20 and 10 letters. However, it is significantly slower than other methods when the numbers are low e.g., m=3 and 2 letters. So I guess that if performance is critical it's good to have an idea of the magnitude of your data before choosing the technique to process them

Comment: It's great and the timing plots are very impressive!

Comment: @AlbertWinestein It sure is. The turning point may be between `m ~ 50` and `m ~ 3` for `n` in the `(2, 20)` range. Eventually the preferential method should be picked based on "local" timings anyways. However, it is common in computer science to pay more attention to the limit of large `n` because for small `n` even if it the relative speed difference is high, the absolute difference is small, while for larger `n` usually the relative and absolute speed go in pair. Obviously, if this is part of a larger problem, the optimization cannot ignore its context.

Answer (score 2):

You need to iterate on both the range of numbers and the list of strings

```
In [106]: [s+str(i) for i in range(1,4) for s in ['a','b']]
Out[106]: ['a1', 'b1', 'a2', 'b2', 'a3', 'b3']
```

Comment: Very concise and exact code!

Answer (score 1):

You can have more than one `for` in a list comprehension:

```py
prefixes = ['a', 'b', 'c']
m = 3

output = [f"{prefix}{num}" for num in range(1, m+1) for prefix in prefixes]
print(output) # ['a1', 'b1', 'c1', 'a2', 'b2', 'c2', 'a3', 'b3', 'c3']
```

If you have multiple `for`s, those will be nested, as in

```py
for num in range(1, m+1):
    for prefix in prefixes:
        ...
```

Comment: Nice and clearly-structured coding!

Answer (score 1):

You could use [`itertools.product`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.product) to get all combinations of the the letters and the `m` range and then join them in an f-string (rather than using `join` as one element is an integer so would require converting to a string):

```py
[f'{x}{y}' for x, y in itertools.product(range(1, m+1), ['a', 'b'])]
```

Output:

```
['a1', 'b1', 'a2', 'b2', 'a3', 'b3']
```

Comment: Very neat but significantly slower (by a factor of ~30%) than a traditional list comprehension (Python 3.10.5 on macOS)

Comment: @AlbertWinestein yeah, it comes out about 25% slower on my Win11 machine; but I would expect that as the lists get larger the performance difference ought to decrease

Comment: @AlbertWinestein I suspect that is because of the small size of the data

Comment: @Nick I do not understand why I get such a significant difference (but I do) when I unpack the return from *product* like this: [f'{y}{x}' for x, y in itertools.product(range(1, m+1), ['a', 'b'])]

Comment: @AlbertWinestein interesting, that is quite a bit (10-15%) faster on my machine too. I guess perhaps it's having to pack the values into a tuple and then unpack them again. Regardless I'll update the answer. Thanks

Comment: Elegant and readily comprehensible code!